# How to calculate the total sum in HTML table

Tags: google-apps-script

I have updated the google sheet tables in Web Apps and in this web app with date picker and other filter option. My table consists of some numbers (Row-Chargeback  ) I am trying to generate the grand total (Sum) in the top left of my web app.

This should show only the number of selected days

[image]

for detailed script refer the sheet [sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HUCNyzv04GAul0-0bBBd6W6oyV2scSyKBnX9XuOcPr0/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [sum() api](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/sum()) from datatable to get total of amount. You need to add below cdn.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/api/sum().js"></script>
```

Add HTML element before table tag, to display the sum amount.

```
<p id="sum"></p>
```

And then add the below callback function during the table datatable initialization.

```
drawCallback: function () {
              var api = this.api();
              $("#sum").html(
                "Total Amount: "+api.column( 4, {page:'current'} ).data().sum().toLocaleString()
              );
            }
```

Note: Since you are using multiple plug-ins, it is beneficial in terms of performance to combine the plug-ins into a single CDN Link wherever possible, rather than making multiple requests to the DataTables CDN.

Comment: use `toLocaleString('en-IN')`