# Mandatory attribute not working in html webapp

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using HTML webapp form and the fields are selected as a mandatory (required) but I am able to submit the data without updating required fields.

Below are my detailed HTML and gs script, help me to fix the concern

```js
 <script>
        function submitForm(btnClicked) {
            $("button").attr("disabled", true);
            var jsonObj = {};
            jsonObj["Project Name"] = $("#ProjectName").val();
             jsonObj["updateBtn"] = $(btnClicked).text();
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(afterSaving).saveDate(jsonObj);
        }
        
                function afterSaving() {
            alert("Thanks, Your response has been recorded");
            $("button").attr("disabled", false);
        }
    </script>
```

```html
<form action="" method="get">
<div class="container"> 
 <table class="table table-bordered" width="" style="width:54%">
    <thead>
    
      <tr class="one">
        <th width="33%">
Project Name

</th>
       
       
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        
        <td><div class="form-group txt">
<input  name="" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" id="ProjectName" required="required">
</div></td>
       
      </tr>
      
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
  
  <div class="container">
<div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
<div class="form-group">
    <button style="display:block;width:100%" id="updateBtn" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" onclick="submitForm()" >Save</button>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its working for me...if needed provide the link of the script

Comment: Please find the sheet Url 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wvysoIQP_i9H66ImLL78Aa2M2auPbfPggUFU9KxbsRg/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `onclick="submitForm()"` and instead add `onsubmit="submitForm()"` in the form tag.

```
<form onsubmit="return submitForm()">
```

Also, add `return false;` to submitForm function.

Comment: Thanks, It's working 
How can i get the numbers in Indian rupee format

Comment: I guess I have answered it over here, [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706820/how-to-calculate-the-total-sum-in-html-table/45708761?noredirect=1#comment78422513_45708761). Lets not mix questions.

Comment: After successful submission page redirects to a blank page, how can I stop this ...?

Comment: change to this `<form onsubmit="return submitForm()">`